# Scrolling <div> with no Dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well this might be a dumb question, but is there ANY way to use both `width: 100%` and `overflow: auto` in an element's CSS?  I am working on a piece of code that will be inserted into a page containing lots of other things.  Since I have no control over the rest of the page, I can't use a fixed height.  I need a way to make my div scroll horizontally so that I can display a varied amount of information.  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** A fiddle of the page can be found [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kCnXQ/6/)

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but the question is vague, please describe in more detail.

Comment: Have you tried width: 100%; and overflow-x: scroll; ?

Comment: Yes, the scrollbar shows up as expected, but it is disabled and the browser's scrollbar is used to show the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Need more info. I guess I don't really understand what you mean by height: 100%. do you have a test page to look at? Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'll try to come up with one, but in the mean time, I have a table with width set to 80% that contains a div with 'style="width:100%; overflow: auto;"', but whenever there is too much information in the div, the entire table stretches and the browser window's scroll bar is used to show the data (with 'overflow-x: scroll', the scrollbar shows up on the div, but it remains disabled even when the browser's scrollbar shows up).

Comment: Can you clarify: "entire table stretches" - do you mean vertically and horizontally? You say <table>, but then you say <div>, so it's hard to understand. It would be very helpful to see a stripped-down example.

Comment: For one thing, it seems like you should try putting a width on the <body> with overflow: auto, which should prevent the horizontal browser scrollbar from appearing.

Comment: Sorry- that was confusing.  There is a table, contained by a div, contained by a table.  As for the body, I can't control that- I can only control the table that contains the div and further down- the rest of the code is already existing and not something I can edit at all.  I've almost finished a fiddle with a version of the page, and I will post it in the OP above.